Boundary Layer Growth for Compressible turbulent flow
I intend to use the flat plate analogy to compare results that ive obtained via matlab and see if they match up, and am looking particularly at compressible, turbulent flow. I noticed that the Blasius solution for boundary layer thickness exists for both a laminar and turbulent incompressible flow, but i couldnt find anything for a compressible case. I'm guessing this would have some relation and be a function of the Mach number as well. Could anyone help?

Aren't there methods like Colebrook-White etc?

What speeds are we talking about, subsonic or supersonic?

The Speed is Mach 2.5, Will have to check on the Colebrook-White method.
